# rough, pixelates edges on buttons in phonegap android

Tags: android, css, cordova

I am developing a mobile app on android using phonegap. However, I the buttons are rough and pixelated around the edges. Can I get any input on how to fix this? Thanks

I tried using jquery mobile but the same thing happens. The button edges are pixelated

Comment: are you using jquery mobile or sencha touch?

Comment: I tried jquery mobile but the same thing happens

Comment: what format of image you using?

Comment: Im not using an image. Just the button tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I use phonegap build service to build the app. But when I export my app using Android tools in eclipse i get rid of that problem. Edges were fine, no harm.